# How to custom live camera with more surfaceview in a screen?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-custom-view

I need to custom view with live camera. I want my screen is divided into 9 parts, per part is show camera preview as photo below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can attach only one SurfaceView to live stream, and you cannot apply different 'effects' to this live preview. You can use OpenGL to resolve both limitations. See examples at https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/TextureFromCameraActivity.java and https://github.com/Sveder/CardboardPassthrough/tree/master/OpenGL%20Version.